# selenium cannot find element using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select

This is the html I got and I'm trying to select this fsuser and use send_keys to input some value.
I tried this:

```
input_username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
```

But is says:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"}
(Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.74)
```

[HTML1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0RjH.png)
[HTML2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKuw1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `name` attribute, no need for the absolute xpath.

try this:

**Css:**

```
input[name='fsuser']
```

use it like this:

```
input_username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='fsuser']")))
input_username.send_keys('some name')
```

**OR**

**xpath:**

```
//input[@name='fsuser']
```

use it like this:

```
input_username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='fsuser']")))
input_username.send_keys('some name')
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update:**

NoSuchElementException:

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML-DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//input[@name='fsuser']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If this is unique `//input[@name='fsuser']` then you need to check for the below conditions as well.

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.

   **Solution:** switch to iframe/frame/frameset first and then interact with this web element.
2. Check if it's in any `shadow-root`.

   **Solution:** Use `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector` to have returned a web element and then operates accordingly.
3. Make sure that the element is rendered properly before interacting with it. Put some `hardcoded delay` or `Explicit wait` and try again.

   **Solution:** `time.sleep(5)` or

   `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='vaadin-text-field-container']//descendant::input[@part='value' and starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'vaadin-text-field-input')]"))).send_keys("test")`
4. If you have redirected to a `new tab/ or new windows` and you have not **switched** to that particular `new tab/new window`, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.

   **Solution:** switch to the relevant window/tab first.
5. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first `switch to default content` and then interact with it.

   **Solution:** switch to default content and then switch to respective iframe.

Comment: Hi cruisepandey, I tried your suggesstions. But seems still not working. It shows' TimeoutException: Message: <empty>'. I just updated the HTML screenshot. There is an <script> at the bottom of the HTML, not sure if it caused the problem.

Comment: check if we've a unique entry in `HTMLDOM` or not, steps are mentioned above.

Comment: Cannot get result by search ``` /input[@name='fsuser'] ```.

Comment: you are missing a `/`, use this `//input[@name='fsuser']`

Comment: Also I suspect this could be in an iframe, Just scroll little bit up, do you see any iframe in HTML ?

Comment: updated HTML file in the op. please see HTML1 and HTML2 link. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Is it possible to share the link to the page? I don't see any iframe though in the screenshot, you can very well check with `//iframe`

Comment: I don't see any iframe. This is an internal website so it doesn't have a public IP.

Comment: What is the error with


`time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='fsuser']").send_keys('some name')`
?

Comment: Also, Update above with all the conditions where one may get NoSuchElement Exception.

Comment: If I use //input[@name='fsuser'], then there is only one line got highlighted. The result of "driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='fsuser']").send_keys('some name')" is "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='fsuser']"}"

Comment: then this xpath is correct `//input[@name='fsuser']` all you have to do now is to debug the way I have mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did work after I do 'switch to the current tab'. The problem is solved by #4.